# "Back to square one" problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

There's a problem I've been stuck on in preparation for junior programming contest I'm going to participate in. It is as follows:

> The "back to square one" problem is played on a board that has $n$ squares in a row and $n-1$ probabilities. Players take turns playing. On their first turn, a player advances to square $1$.After the first turn, if a player is on square $i$ , the player advances to square $i + 1$ with probability $p(i)$ , and returns to square 1 with probability $1-p(i)$ .The player is finished upon reaching square $n$. Compute the expected number of turns to complete the game.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ From the definition of expectation we know that

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\cdot P(i)= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\cdot(1-p(i))\cdot p(i)$$

I'm not really sure what to do with this expression. Perhaps it follows a negative binomial distribution. But, the CDF for this is really ugly and I think it would be beyond the scope of this contest.

Comment: Is it required that $n \geq 2$?

Comment: @Clarinetist yes, I seemed to have had left that out. My apologies

Comment: Are you familiar with Markov processes and transition matrices?

Comment: @hardmath no actually. I only did a course in basic probability theory in undergrad.

Comment: An easy test case is $p(i)=1$ which should give $E(X)=n$. Try it on your expression.

Comment: From the description of "a junior programming contest" I would imagine "[c]ompute the expected number of turns to complete the game" to mean write a program to do such a computation.  Without needing much background in the matrix modelling, I suspect you can see your way through to evaluating the expected number of turns to complete the game by induction/recursion.

Comment: Or use Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: so beautiful question

Comment: My answer has been edited.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(i)$ be the expected number of turns when you are on square $i$. Then you have the recurrence for $i=1, 2,3,\dots n-1$:
$$f(i) =1+ f(i+1)p(i)+f(1)(1-p(i)), \; f(n)=0$$
and we seek $f(0)=1+f(1)$. This gives you a linear system to solve.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f(i)=1+f(i+1)p(i)+f(1)(1-p(i))$ ?

Comment: @posilon I missed that, thought it would just go back one step on failure. Thanks.  Corrected the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, you need to win $n-1$ in a row.  The chance of doing that is $\prod_i p(i)$, so it takes $\frac 1{\prod_i p(i)}$ tries.  You need to work out the average length of a failed try.  It is $1\ \  1-p(1)$ of the time, $2\ \ p(1)(1-p(2))$ of the time, and so on.  Add those up, remembering that you must fail $n-2$ for this calculation.  If the average length of a failure is $x$, you have $\frac x{\prod_i p(i)}+n-1$ for the expected time to success

Comment: You say that (on average) it takes $1/\prod_i p(i)$ tries, not failed tries. So why the answer is not just $y/\prod_i p(i)$ where $y$ is the average length of a try (failed and successful tries included)?

Comment: Good point that I had missed.  The reset to start made me think of what I showed.  They are both correct.  I think you will find the same equation either way.

Comment: Indeed, they are the same. But you should not fail $n-2$ for the calculation of $x$. It is $x=1 \cdot (1-p_1)+2p_1(1-p_2)+ \dots + (n-1)p_1p_2\dots p_{n-2}(1-p_1)$ and $y=x+(n-1)p_1p_2\dots p_{n-2} p_{n-1}$ where p_i:=p(i).

Comment: Note that $x$ is not the average length of a failure: The probabilities $(1-p_1),p_1(1-p_2),\dots,p_1p_2 \dots p_{n-2}(1-p_{n-1})$ do not add up to $1$. (I hadn't realized this at first, and this is why the equality $n-1+x/\prod_i p(i) = y/\prod_i p(i)$ looked rather strange to me.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of knowing after how many iterations a transient markov state gets absorbed into the absorbing state.

[Wikipedia helps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps)!

Basically fill a matrix $A$ with the probabilities of the markov chain, remove the last column and last row that correspond to the absorbing state, you have $Q$.

Then $N = (I - Q)^{-1}$, and the answer is the sum of the first row of $N$.