# Back to square 1...

Tags: probability, markov-chains

A friend of mine was telling me about one of the problems, which he described thus:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the answer to the toy problem presented here is reportedly 13. However, I don't understand how they arrive at that number.

As I understand it, this diagram is a Markov chain and the problem can be solved by premultiplying the initial-state vector

$$
x_0 = [1,0,0]^T
$$

by the following (left) stochastic matrix

$$
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 0.75 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0    & 0 \\
0   & 0.25 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(where $T_{ij}$ corresponds to the probability of a transition to state $i$ while in state $j$) 
as many times ($k$) as it takes for the last entry in the state vector to be $\geq 0.5$. The answer is then $k+1$, because you need to add $1$ for the very first turn (the one that initially takes you to Square 1).

According to my reasoning, the answer should be 10, not 13. How did they arrive at 13?

Comment: Certainly related: ["Back to square one" problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980270/back-to-square-one-problem).  To the extent that a careful examination of the code shown is sought, this makes the Question off-topic for Math.SE, but note that "hitting times" can be calculated by the techniques discussed in the earlier Question.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the link; I'll give it a read. I've only included my code as a supporting explanation for my reasoning. I don't expect answerers to "debug" it for me. I just want to know where my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I'm not voting to close.  I think a tailored explanation of why 13 is the answer to the "toy problem" is different enough to get a good Answer here.  Perhaps the code can be de-emphasized somehow, but I'm not too hung up on appearances.

Comment: I considered (but decided against) voting to close both for being a duplicate and for being off-topic.  As is, it's easy for a Reader to mistakenly think it's the first time the general problem is being raised here.

Comment: @hardmath The recurrence in the highest-voted answer to the question you link to doesn't make sense to me; it seems to be backward or something. In particular, we're looking for $f(n)$, not $f(0)$.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying an initial vector by the k-th power of the transition matrix you will only get the distribution of your state at step k. You need to learn/return to the basics of probability theory and Markov chains. I can recommend Grimmett and Stirzaker's book [Probability and Random Processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198572220).

Comment: I know that "multiplying an initial vector by the $k$-th power of the transition matrix you will only get the distribution of your state at step $k$". But shouldn't the smallest $k$ such that the probability to be on the last square be $\geq .5$, plus one, be the solution? Your answer is too handwavy... Can you explain why the solution to the toy problem is 13?

Comment: It's a sound observation, but this would be better as a Comment since it doesn't attempt to explain why "the answer to the toy problem presented here is reportedly 13".

Comment: It answers to the question "Where did I go wrong" and points to a concrete literature where to learn basic notions such as the expectation.

Comment: @Valentas:  The general problem has already been dealt with by a previous Math.SE Question (see link in Comments above).  I think the opportunity is there to provide a more detailed Answer to the specifics of the "toy problem".

Comment: @hardmath: agreed, sorry did not see the newest comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple recursion solution:-

$$F(i) = 1+ \frac{F(i-1)}{p(i-1)} ,\,\ i= 0,1,2,3....n\\
    F(0)=0$$

According to given problem,
    $$F(3) = 1+ \frac{F(2)}{.25}$$
    $$F(2) = 1+ \frac{F(1)}{.5}$$
    $$F(1) = 1+ \frac{F(0)}{p(0)}=1$$
    So,$$F(2) = 1+ 1\cdot2 =3$$
    So,$$F(3) = 1+ 3\cdot4 = 13$$

Comment: Use Mathjax to format your equations.

Comment: Thanks @Aniket !, I'm new to the community......   Feel free to edit! :)